# How insert bulk upload in postgresql using Sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, restify

I use **Sequelize** to write **ORM** queries in nodejs, but now i want to **insert data in bulk** format from **Data.js** file which contains data , But i getting error in my console
**error:**
**.........
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
not inserted...ReferenceError: myusers is not defined**
so tell me how to solve this?

```
const restify=require('restify')
const server=restify.createServer()
const Data=require('./Data')
//connection with database
const Sequelize=require('sequelize')
const connection = new Sequelize('emadb', 'postgres', 'Groot@2498', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect:  'postgres' 
  });
connection
.sync({
    logging:console.log('.........')
})
.then(()=>{
    myusers.bulkCreate(Data)
    server.listen(8080,function(){
        console.log('insert info server started')
    })
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log('not inserted...'+err)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

`ReferenceError: myusers is not defined`

is pretty specified You have:

`myusers.bulkCreate(Data)`

but I (nor the program) don't see anywhere you define `myusers` before you use it.

Comment: myusers is table in my postgresql database

Comment: That may be so, but the program has to know about it. I'm not that familiar with Sequelize, but it uses models to map database tables: [Models](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-definition.html). [Usage](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html). So you need to make the program aware of the model you are using in order to get at the bulkCreate() on the model.